# Return alternate view results if first select returns 0 count

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

i have quite a long SQL select in a SQL Server view.

However, I want a condition on it, so that if no rows are returned, then it changes the where clause.

An overview of the query is as follows:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4............(15 columns)
FROM TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 ON t1 = t2 (10 tables)
WHERE a = b
```

So what i want, is if the above query returns 0 rows, then return the results of:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4............(15 columns)
FROM TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 ON t1 = t2 (10 tables)
WHERE a = c
```

How can I go about this in a view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use an `or` condition.. `WHERE a = b or a = c`

Comment: But i dont want to return a = c if a = b has values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`not exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)**

```
;with cte as (
  /* big query here without where clause of `a = b` or `a = c` */
)
select * 
from cte
where a = b
  or ( a = c
    and not exists (select 1 from cte where a = b)
      )
```

example:

```
create table t (value int);
insert t values (0),(1),(3),(4),(5);
with cte as (
  select *
  from t
)
select * 
from cte
where value = 2
  or ( value = 3 
    and not exists (select 1 from cte where value=2)
      )
```

returns `3`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NDC30620

Comment: This approach looks like it should work. Would there be much of a performance hit or anything with CTE?

Comment: @DaRoGa the cte itself has no performance hit, as used here it is only used to keep the query DRY by not repeating the main query in the `not exists()`. It will depend on the performance of the queries themselves. Using a cte with recursion is what could be associated with a performance hit, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Select both sets and prioritize the one having `a = b` over the one having `a = c` using `RANK`:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4............(15 columns)
FROM (
   SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                   WHEN a = b THEN 1
                                   ELSE 2
                                END) AS rnk,
          COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4............(15 columns)
   FROM TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 ON t1 = t2 (10 tables)
   WHERE a IN (b, c)) AS t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

If some records having `a = b` do exist, then the query will pick exactly these records, otherwise it will return the ones having `a = c`.